# Scaling down a PDF using ghostscript results in images not being alinged

Tags: html, css, pdf, phantomjs, ghostscript

I am currently rendering a specific webpage using phantomjs, containing among other things two overlaying images. After the PDF has been generated, i'm rescaling the generated PDF to an appropriate size - currently it's being downscaled to approximately a third of the original size. When comparing the converted PDF of phantomjs to the one being downscaled, i can clearly see that the images are no more being aligned (which they are in the converted one)

Have a look at the zoomed in (3200%, to show the problem in detail) area, where the problem occurs. The blue image (SVG) is overlaying the darker one (PNG) - both are perfectly aligned on the right side (the white area is part of the PDF))
[image: Converted]

However, when scaling this image using ghostscript: `gs -o /path/to/output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFFitPage -r300x300 -g2676x2676 /path/to/input.pdf` (even if it gets *down*scaled, and not *up*scaled, the images are no longer aligned:
[image]

(Both images are placed with `position:absolute; right: 0;`, so both align on the right side nicely.)

What could cause such a behaviour and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is, probably, in the PDF consumer, not in Ghostscript.

You first need to note that when you run a PDF file through Ghostscript and produce a PDF file via the pdfwrite device you are absolutely **not** 'resizing', 'downscaling', 'merging' or any other term which implies that the content of the output PDF file bears any relation to the content of the input.

The 'Overview' [here](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/VectorDevices.htm) explains why, I'd suggest you read it.

Now I cannot tell for absolute certain without seeing the PDF files (which you have not given us) but.. the overwhelmingly likely reason is that rounding errors in arithmetic mean that the images in the output PDF file are not in **precisely** the same position as the input (and no, there's no way to avoid that).

When you 'zoom in' you are altering the Current Transformation Matrix, tiny differences in the arithmetic precision of the co-ordinates are multiplied by the 'zoom factor'. Usually pixels are 'on' if the object covers more than 1/2 of the pixel, if the scaling works out just right it could easily mean that the pixel in the top image (assuming it **is* an image) is just barely over 1/2 pixel while the image below is just barely under 1/2 pixel. Resulting in the mismatch you see.

This sort of problem can exist even without the kind of transformation you are doing, a trained graphic designer is aware of this and creates content in ways which prevent the problem occurring. Either don't have images which are required to be precisely aligned or, if you must, then have the images both extend past the point where you want them to end, then place a clipping rectangle around both images. That way no matter how the clip rectangle is scaled, the images will always be clipped at the same point.